# ClickOnce deployment for Terminal Service Recieving COM Error

Tags: clickonce, terminal-services

I've deployed a desktop application utilizing 3rd party dll's to a test terminal server in order to report its viablity. In my testing I've received this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in General Purpose.dll

Additional information: Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {8EB296F1-6C46-4BC1-9F00-B49F14B57DB8} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800a0035.
```

It occurs when a new third-party class is created (one that is vital to the application). As far as I can tell this is the only third-party class having such issues, but the only one in this DLL.

The application deploys properly using ClickOnce for a normal desktop to use, but will not work for the TS session or the server console.

All the DLLs are set as "Copy Local" and I've confirmed they were copied into the users local settings "Apps\2.0\crazylongnamehere" folder.

I've chosen to go the publish route (over MSI) since we currently have thick clients and the thin clients will be integrated slowly over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with copying referenced files to the output location, I finally got my app to work on TS.

The solution was to add the referenced dll's to the project as linked items and changed the properties to:

- Build Action: Content
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always

Once both these were updated it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on one of these terminal servers and you drill down into the ClickOnce cache and double-click on the [exe] file, does it work? Or does it crash? Does it require any kind of privileges to do what you're trying to do?